# how to dispose googlemap object?

Tags: google-maps

I am using the Google Maps Control for ASP.Net. I am adding one point which is current point of bus & polyline of the points from current point to last 10 points on the page load with showing popup on current point by default.

I am using update panel for the the refresh button. There is also one input field which takes number of record to show on polyline from current point. Now I want to reset my googlemapObject on refresh button click event so that in every refresh click completely new set of points, polylines should add and shown on google map.

Is there is any method like dispose to dispose current object of goolemap.
How to resolve this problem?

Regards,
Girish

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you are using the Google Maps Control for ASP.NET found at:

- http://en.googlemaps.subgurim.net/

If that is the case - there is an example found on their site that will walk you through how to erase icons that are added to the map.

The sample code can be found right here:

- http://en.googlemaps.subgurim.net/ejemplos/ejemplo_99000_Custom-Javascript.aspx

By implementing a custom Javascript Event you will be able to change the data on your map with the refresh button - without needing to do a whole page refresh.